# API for Http Request/Response in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

In the iPhone application whether all the network operations are done ONLY using the `NSURLConnections`?? I am using the NSURLConnections and its delegate methods `ConnectiondidReceiveResponse`,`ConnectiondidFinishLoading`,etc to download the files.

My question is whether `NSURLConnection` API available only in cocoa-touch for the Http request/reponse ? Is there any other API available ??

Can we use the `NSURLConnection` for uploading the files also ??

I guess there are many questions , but I am really confused. Please help me out !

Comment: the best way to manage the network: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: Thnks @WhiteTiger,I knew that ASIHTTPRequest is available. But I tend to use the Default API provided by apple.

Comment: I agree with @WhiteTiger

Comment: @WhiteTiger: ASIHTTPRequest is now outdated and not under active development. You should consider using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try the MKNetworkKit framework:
[MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit)

Easy to use and works really fine!

Answer (score 1):

I feel difficulty to upload file with `NSURLConnection`, too. Finally, I use `AFNetworking` Library. It works very well.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api-base-url.com"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"], 0.5);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"avatar" fileName:@"avatar.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];
[operation start];
```

You can find the library page at below address.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

In addition, there is CocoaPods which manage libraries of objective-C. I'm trying to use it.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/